# Cannot boot debian after upgrading windows 10 on dual boot

Tags: windows-10, debian, multi-boot, grub2

I had my SSD set up with two partitions, one for Windows 7 and one for Debian. Set up with GNU Grub 2, so that I can dual-boot. This has been working fine for years.

Today I decided to put an Windows 10 on the Windows 7 partition, got the .iso, made a bootable USB and told Windows to install on the Windows 7 partition (Wouldn't even allow me to put it on the other partition). Windows 10 gets installed, everything is good.

However GNU Grub does not launch when I start my PC, and even if I try to boot from the Debian partition from BIOS nothing happens.

I saw some previous replies, that you should run boot-repair and what not. But I guess it's only relevant for Ubuntu? I have an bootable USB with Debian on it, such that I can launch live (I can see all my debian files are still there). But I do not know how to recover.

Comment: You have to mount the relevant partitions and reinstall Grub.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Windows, you need to disable “Secure Boot”
[See this page by Microsoft about disabling Secure Boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/disabling-secure-boot)

Secure Boot is a Windows feature, which is on by default, and it will skip any GRUB.

In addition to this, as mentioned in the comments, your Master Boot Record was more than likely overwritten by Windows’ own generated MBR. You will need to reinstall GRUB and rebuild the MBR. **Do NOT recreate the partition table.**
You can follow [this guide that was written to handle this very situation among others](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm).

Comment: FYI, Windows will always overwrite the MBR and skip GRUB, even without secure boot..